# Photoshop export to PDF - Shape issues

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, vector, pdf

This little screenshot explains well the issue. I have shapes from Photoshop (also made a test from copying shapes from Illustrator) and exporting to PDF.

Here is the ugly results. If I reduce the size of the shape it becomes uglier.

Any help ?

[image]

Comment: What's the resolution (PPI) of your Photoshop document?

Comment: 300 Pixels/Inch

Comment: Thank you Vincent ! I discovered the Chat feature. It seems really interesting. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, I found a solution. It seems that the problem comes from *Automate-PDF Presentation...* When I use this tool to create my pdf, the shapes are deformed.

But if I export every pages separately in PDF format using *Save As...* there is no problem.

Then to merge all the pages I use an online webservice.

I agree that this is not really an explanation but more a workaround.